Can you store $2(2^n -1)$ classical bits of information in $n$ qubits?
I just had a lecture where my professor said that the relation in the title of the post was valid. He even told us that we could for example store 1TB of data, in just 35 qubits. But does this mean that theoretically (ignoring states being unstable and stuff like that) we could for example somehow encode the data of the entire internet in just 100 qubits (or less)? My confusion stems from this reddit post that I found https://www.reddit.com/r/QuantumComputing/comments/j9dcjq/what_is_the_limit_of_storing_information_with/ . The top comment there says that the relation only holds one way around; $n$ qubits require $2^n$ classical bits to be properly stored/represented, but you cannot store $2^n$ classical bits in $n$ qubits. So which is it?

You can even store an infinite number of bits in a single qubit! Just encode it in the amplitude, written in binary. (More seriously, the claim is for the least highly misleading.)

A $n$-qubit state can be represented by a linear combination of the $2^{n}$ vectors of the standard computational basis $\left\{\left|0\dots 00\right\rangle, \left|0\dots 0 1\right\rangle,\dots, \left|10\dots 0\right\rangle,\dots, \left|1\dots 11\right\rangle\right\}$. To accurately describe a quantum state over $n$ qubits, you thus need $2^{n}$ coefficients (aka amplitudes) which are complex numbers in general.
If we consider only quantum states where all coefficients are either 0 or 1 (up to normalization), you would need $2^{n}$ classical bits to describe the state, these bits encoding which basis kets appear in the state written in the computational basis. This shows that you need at least $2^{n}$ classiscal bits to properly represent a $n$-qubit state in the computational basis.
"Storing" classical bits into qubits is not very well defined. You can describe some quantum states with the convention I just described using $2^{n}$ classical bits, and anyone having access to the full representation of the state can trivially retrieve the original bits.
However, given one copy of a qubit in an unknown state, you cannot work out its representation in the computation basis. To gain some information, you would have to measure the state, collapsing it to a computational basis vector according to its unknown amplitudes. You will get to know the value of one classical bit "stored" in the qubit and you will lose forever the $2^{n}-1$ others.
Generally speaking, quantum measurement makes it so that you cannot extract more than $n$ classical bits of information out of a quantum state, even though qubits live in a $2^{n}$-dimensional Hilbert space.
